# Sufficient condition for deformation retraction of manifold on its subcomplex

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be $n$-dimensional manifold. It is quite obvious that if $X$ is deformation retract of $M$ of positive codimenstion then $H_{n}(M; G) = 0$ for any coefficient group $G$

I am interested in opposite statement. Assume $H_{n}(M; G) = 0$ for any coefficient group $G$. **Is it true that there exists cellulary subcomplex of positive codimension $X \subset M$ such that $X$ is deformation retract (or at least homotopically equivalent) of $M$?**

**My attempt**: I think that I managed to proof that there exists $X \subset M$ of positive codimension such that $X$ is homotopically equivalent to $M$ if $H_{n}(M;G) = 0$ and $\pi_{1}(M) = 0$

Note that $H_{n}(M;G) = 0$ implies that $H_{n-1}(M)$ is free. Indeed, by universal coefficient formula $H_{n}(M;G) = H_{n}(M; \mathbb{Z}) \otimes G \oplus \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(M; \mathbb{Z}), G) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Tor}(H_{n-1}(M; \mathbb{Z}), G) = 0$ for any group $G$. Hence, $H_{n-1}(M; \mathbb{Z})$ is free

Let $X$ be some $n-1$-dimensional cellular subcomplex of manifold $M$. Denote $i: X \rightarrow M$ - canonical embedding of subcomplex in complex. Obviously, $i_{*}: H_{k}(X) \rightarrow H_{k}(M)$ is isomoprhism for $k < n - 1$ and for $k \geqslant n$ since $H_{k}(X) = H_{k}(M) = 0$ for $k \geqslant n$

$i_{*}: H_{n-1}(X) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(M)$ is surjection since it is just canonical projection of group $\mathrm{Ker}\partial$ onto $\mathrm{Ker}\partial/\mathrm{Im}\partial$. We know that $H_{n-1}(M)$ is free, hence $\mathrm{Im}\partial \subset \mathrm{Ker}\partial$ should look like $(1,1,\dots,1,1,0,0,\dots,0)$. That implies that all degrees of attaching maps $\partial e^{n} \rightarrow e^{n-1}$ are equal to $1$ or $0$. Hence, we can shrink all these balls in $M$ by some homotopy $f_{t}$ on $M$. This shrinking can destroy all $n$-cells that have non-zero degree attaching map. Let $X' = f_{1}(X)$ and $M' = f_{1}(M)$. Then $X'$ is cellular subcomplex of $M'$ and embedding $i: X' \rightarrow M'$ is isomorphism in all homology groups since $\mathrm{Im}\partial$ is zero in $M'$: this give us isomorphism in $n-1$-dimensional homology group, in other dimensions $i_{*}$ is isomorphism because it was isomorphism on these homology groups before homotopy $f_{t}$ of manifold $M$

Since $i$ is an isomoprphism in all homology groups in simply-connected $CW$-complex, it is homotopy equivalence. **Is there any way to choose $i$ such that it is deformation retraction of $M'$ onto $X'$?**

**Also can one omit condition of simply-connectedness of manifold $M$?**

**Idea**: Maybe it is useful to work with universal cover $N$ of $M$. If we knew that $H_{n}(M;G) = 0$ implies $H_{n}(N;G) = 0$ then the case of manifold with arbitrary fundamental group would be rather simple. **Does there exists a universal cover $N$ of $M$ (Manifold $M$ have $H_{n}(M;G) = 0$ for all coefficient groups $G$) such that $H_{n}(N;G) = 0$ for every coefficient group $G$**?

Comment: Yes, for smooth manifolds: https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/NoncompactSurfaceFree.pdf

Comment: @ConnorMalin, thanks for reference. But there are compact manifold that satisy condition H_{n}=0. For example cylinder S^{1}\times [0,1]

Comment: For a manifold with boundary (the only compact manifolds that have that property), simply remove the boundary and apply the above theorem.

Comment: You are right. Thanks!